# Why does my URL Rewrite rule cause too many redirects on apache?

Tags: regex, apache

I try to change the URLs to my products, so the **categories** between **host** and **product-identifier** wont be displayed anymore:

From:
`www.myexampleshop.de/pants/shortpants/123456790-exampleshortpants`

To:
`www.myexampleshop.de/123456790-exampleshortpants`

My rewrite Rule is builds the URL correctly:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ([\/a-z]+)(?=\d{10}-)(.+) $2$3 [R]
```

But my browser tells me I have too many redirects. How is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Your regex only has capture groups 1 and 2, yet you reference $2 and $3. So no replacement is being done and you are redirecting back to yourself over and over again. I should also add that your example URL only has 9 digits and would never match the regex.

If you are doing a redirect, you could use a [RedirectMatch](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html) directive, which matches the *path* of the URL against a regex and only if it matches then applies the rewrite rule, instead of the RewriteRule directive. I have "adjusted" your regex:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteMatch "^([/a-zA-Z]+)(\d{10}-.+)$" "/$2"
```

If you do not want to use redirects, then use a RewriteRule

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule %{REQUEST_URI} "^([/a-zA-Z]+)(\d{10}-.+)$" "/$2" [L]
```

If you are using the RewriteRule directive (for redirecting or otherwise), you normally add the [L] flag as you probably do not want to apply any additional rewriting rules.